# SQL Server can not find word

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I search for the `Dünyas` word with a `LIKE` operator I can see the results but when I search `Dünyası` word with `LIKE` operator, it returns no results. Problem is not `ı` or `ü` letters I tried with `i` and `u` letters as well.

This query:

```
select * from DbDivx where NameTurkish like '%Dünyas%' =>
```

returns:

```
Boksörün Dünyası
Geleceğin Dünyası
Su Dünyası
```

However:

```
select * from DbDivx where NameTurkish like '%Dünyası%' =>
```

returns nothing.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Ugh, put a prefix before the string literal so SQL Server knows it's a Unicode string. `LIKE N'%Dünyas%'`

Comment: The two select statements are querying different tables???

Comment: @Milen While true, I highly doubt that's the actual problem.

Comment: Is it possible there is an unprintable character between the s and the ı?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Table names are same I edited

Comment: @HLGEM nope there is no unprintable charcter between them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand LIKE N'%Dünyası%' worked!

Comment: Yes, I know. When you have Unicode strings you need to treat them that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c359/1

```
create table test (someName nvarchar(300))

insert into test (someName)
select N'Boksörün Dünyası'
union all select N'Geleceğin Dünyası'
union all select N'Su Dünyası'

select * from test where someName like N'%Dünyası%'
```

Not having any issues with the above fiddle.  Note that when i inserted data without the N in front of it, the like query *did not* return results.

hopefully this helps!